# PHP DOMdocument class does not works in Object Oriented PHP

Tags: php

I am Using `DOMdocument` class of PHP for DOM traversing. When I was using it with procedural PHP it was working fine, but inside a class member function it through this error :

`Class 'generalCrawler\DOMNode' not found in C:\wamp64\www\Fiverr\Job Crawler\crawler3.php on line 14`

I do not know what is the problem, can any one find out :

This is my code :

```js
class CrawlJobs {
  public static
  function getData($html, $link) {

    $document = new DOMdocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $document - > loadHTML($html);
    $elements = $document - > getElementsByTagName("li");

    foreach($elements as $element) {
      if ($element - > hasAttribute("class")) {
        if ($element - > getAttribute("class") == "jl") {
          foreach($element - > childNodes as $subElements) {
            if ($subElements - > hasChildNodes()) {
              foreach($subElements - > childNodes as $nodes) {#
                $this - > getBaseUrl($link).$nodes - > getAttribute("href")
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($nodes);
                echo "<pre>";
              }
            }
          }
        }#
        return $element - > nodeValue.
        "<br>";
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have namspace in your file?

Comment: @u_mulder no just a simple class

Comment: What is `generalCrawler` then?

Comment: @AleksaArsić it still works in procedural syntax

Comment: @u_mulder, oh yeah sorry I have it, I forgot

Comment: Worked, when I removed the namespace @u_mulder

Comment: You could also use `$document = new \DOMdocument();` if you are instantiating object that is not in your namespace.